# Autocomplete not working - Flutter/Dart VS code - Windows

Tags: windows, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

autocomplete code is not working in VS Code, any help please ?

I tried to search for several available solutions since 2 days, and none of them works :(. What should I do to solve this problem?

For example, when I wrote StatelessWidget like shown in the attachment photo, it inserts "StatelessWidget " without completing the rest of the needed code.

Comment: i remember this problem occurs several month ago, since they release flutter 3. they fixed it at latest build, try  to run `flutter upgrade` on terminal. if you dont want to, try to downgrade to flutter 2.10.5

Comment: "attached photo"... what photo...

Comment: Code completion in Dart/Flutter is powered by the Dart Analysis Server, a tool from the Dart SDK. I'd suggest reporting this issue to https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues